# Apache Ignite Logs for joint two tables

Tags: spring-boot, caching, persistence, ignite

I am getting some warn logs from Apache Ignite when i run execute join query. I don't know what to do.
When I create them, I set CacheConfiguration `cfg.setAffinity(AffinityFunction instance);` instance has 24 parts both of them.and also same nodeAffinityKey.

For join two partitioned tables join condition should contain the equality operation of affinity keys. Left side: EMPLOYEE; right side: DEPARTMENT"

I need to solve this.

Comment: What's the reason for changing the default affinity function? We need your configuration and the query you are using. Please add more details to the question.

Comment: Hi @Al , we need to custom AffinityFunction so we wrote. And set both of them (new SingleNodeAffinityFunction(true, 24, groupId) with it. And also my query is

Comment: ` SELECT 
f._KEY AS EMPLOYEE_ID
FROM EMPLOYEE f
JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON d._KEY = f.DEPARTMENT_ID 
WHERE 
f.NAME = ? AND f.SURNAME= ? AND f.ACTIVE= ?  `
I need to get employees which has these criterias and has a departmant.
Thank you @AlexandrShapkin

Comment: Not sure if it's going to work with _KEY. What's your primary key for the DEPARTMENT table? Are both department_key and Employee.Department_ID marked as AffinityKey?

Comment: Check what affinity indexes are defined using "Select * from sys.indexes".

Comment: Please, add your configuration/answers to the question.

Comment: Hi @AlexandrShapkin, i found solution, when i set query like this"setDistributedJoin(true)", i dont get this error any more.Thank you

Comment: Posted that as an answer. Otherwise it's just another question with 0 answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the tables are non-colocated. That means they don't reside on the same node, i.e. no AffinityKey is configured.

By default, Ignite assumes that the data is colocated and JOIN could be done locally. For distributed join of non-colocated tables, an extra configuraiton is required [per the docs](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/distributed-joins#distributed-joins):

> If your query is non-colocated, you have to enable the non-colocated
> mode of query execution by setting
> SqlFieldsQuery.setDistributedJoins(true); otherwise, the results of
> the query execution may be incorrect.